# If $X$ is separable then there exists $D$ a countable symmetric subset of the unit ball $B^*$ in $X^*$ dense with respect to the Mackey topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. $X^*$ will denote the dual of $X$. $B^*$ will denote the unit ball in $X^*$.

$X^*$ equipped with the Mackey topology $\tau(X^*,X)$, i.e. the strongest, locally convex topology $\tau$ on $X^∗$ for which we have $(X^*,\tau )^∗ = X$.

Why there exists a countable subset $D$ of the unit ball $B^*$, symmetric $(D=-D)$ such that:
$$
B^*=\overline{D}^{\tau(X^*,X)}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two key ideas in here: one is a basic sequence of thoughts from functional analysis:  $X$ is separable so $X^*$ is metrisable, and by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem the unit ball $B_{X^*}$ is compact and so is a compact metric space.  Compact metric spaces are separable as well, so we can find a (countable) dense subset of $B_{X^*}$.  This tells us that looking for your subset $D$ has hopes of success.

The second idea is that since $X$ is separable its unit ball $B_X$ contains a dense sequence and we can use this to construct something that has the required properties.  So, let $S=\{x_n\}$ be such a dense sequence.  Since we're talking about the Mackey topology we know that there is a neighbourhood base that is the family of polars of weakly-compact balanced (symmetric) convex subsets of $X$, so let us set 
$$ V^\circ_{X^*} = \{x^* \in X^* \mid |x^*(x_n)|\leq 1 \ \forall x_n \in S\} $$
to be the polar of $S$. It is clear that this is a subset of $B_{X^*}$ and we claim that in fact they are equal:

Suppose $y^* \in V^\circ_{X^*} \setminus B_{X^*} $.  Then $\|y^*\|\gt 1$ and $|y^*(x_n)| \leq 1 \ \forall x_n \in S$  This means that for $x\in B_X$ we have $|y^*(x)| - |y^*(x_n)| \geq |y^*(x_n)-y^*(x)| = |y^*(x_n-x)| \gt \varepsilon \gt 0$.  But we also know that $\|y^*(x_n-x)\| \leq \|y^*\|\cdot\|x_n-x \| < \varepsilon$, which is impossible.  So no such $y^*$ exists and $V^\circ_{X^*} = B_{X^*}$.

So now we choose our symmetric countable dense subset $D$ from $V^\circ_{X^*}$ where the symmetry property is available to us because the polar is symmetric.

Comment: Why if   $y^* \in V^\circ_{X^*} \setminus B_{X^*} $.  Then $\|y^*\|\leq 1$ and $|y^*(x_n)|>1 \ \forall x_n \in S$ ?

Comment: @KarimKHAN by the definitions of $V^\circ_{X^*}$ and $B_{X^*}$

Comment: But if $y^* \in V^\circ_{X^*} \setminus B_{X^*} $.  Then  $y^* \in V^\circ_{X^*} $ and $y^*\notin B_{X^*} $.Then $\|y^*\|>1$ and $|y^*(x_n)|\leq 1 \ \forall x_n \in S$

Comment: @KarimKHAN Ok, thanks.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: Sir, can you explain to me why, you wrote in the last paragraph that: "So now, we choose our dense subset symmetric countable $D$ of $V_{X^∗}^{\circ}$....".

Comment: @KarimKHAN We know that $B_{X^*}$ possesses a countable dense subset because it's a compact metric space, so we can select a countable dense subset from it.  We have shown that $V^\circ_{X^*} = B_{X^*}$ so we know that we can add in any point we need to that countable dense subset to make it symmetric -- which is what we require for $D$ (for example, pick a countable dense subset from $B_{X^*}$ and then add in $-x$ for every $x\in D$).

Comment: If $X$ is separable, the set $B_{X^∗}$ furnished with the relative $w^∗$-topology is compact and metrizable. Can we say that this is true for Mackey's topology?

Comment: @kakaHae you seem to have asked this question on MathOverflow (and it should be a question, not a comment) so I'll leave MO to provide you with an answer.

Comment: @posmortes, we say that $H=:span_{\mathbb{Q}}(D)$ is countable Mackey dense subset of $X$. Can we say that $H $ separete the points of $X$?

Comment: @AbdessamadEl I think you should ask this as a new question as I don't really understand what you're saying.  $H$ would separate points of $X$ if it consisted of functionals defined on $X$ into $\mathbb R$ such that any pair of points in $X$ are given different values by some functional in $H$.  But $H$ is a subset of $X$ so unless $X^*=X$ I don't see how you're finding functionals.

Comment: No, $H$ is subset  of $X^*$,  I made a mistake, because $D$ is a dense subset in the unit ball of $X^*$ for mackey topology.

Comment: @AbdessamadEl ah, in that case, yes you can say that $H$ separates points of $X$.  Given any point $x\in X,\ x\not=0$ we can find $\alpha \in {\mathbb R}$ so that $\alpha x \in B_{X^*}$.  Then there is a functional $x^*$ and a slice $S(x^*, \gamma, B_{X^*})$ that contains $x$.  The functional $x^*$ thus separates $x$ from other points in $X$.  (You might need to look up what a slice is; if you want to ask about it, *please* write a new question, do not add a comment here)